# Trouble with rendering background boxes class from a 2d list in pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I am trying to make a background of boxes for a simple snake game by iterating through a 2d array and drawing boxes which I've stored as instances of a class BackgroundCube in each part of the array. When I run the program there are no errors, but nothing shows up on the pygame screen.

I've printed the length of each sublist which shows a length of 20, my desired grid size. I've also just printed the entire array which shows what I believe to be instances of the class, something like this: <**main**.BackgroundCube object at 0x11186e090> would be one entry in the list. So I believe the problem lies in how I'm drawing the rectangles.

```
python

WIDTH = 400
HEIGHT = 420
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))

class BackgroundCube:
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height, color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.color = color

    def draw(self, screen):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, self.color, (self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height), 2)

def redrawGameWindow():
    for x in range(20):
        for y in range(20):
            cube2 = background_cube_list[x][y]
            cube2.draw(screen)

run = True
background_cube_list = [[0 for x in range(int(WIDTH/20))] for x in range(int((HEIGHT-20)/20))]
while run:
    for cube in range(int(WIDTH / 20)):
        for cube1 in range(int((HEIGHT - 20) / 20)):
            background_cube_list[cube][cube1] = BackgroundCube(cube * 20, cube1 * 20, 20, 20, (144, 144, 144))
    clock.tick(30)

    redrawGameWindow()
```

Again, no errors, just a blank white window. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to add

```
pygame.display.update()
```

in your main loop. Add it just after `redrawGameWindow()`.

You also need to define `clock`, which I guess is `clock = pygame.time.Clock()`. Add it before the main loop.